# call converter in XAML if property of a object in the observable collection changes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, observablecollection

I have a converter that accepts an `ObservableCollection` as a parameter, and I'd like to re-evaluate it whenever a specific property on any item in the collection changes

For example: lets say I have bound a label to a collection of `Person` objects with a converter. The job of the converter is to count the number of Persons in the list that are female, and return "valid" for 1 female or "accepted" for 2. I'd like the converter to get called again anytime the `Gender` property on any `Person` object gets changed.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a classic problem you end up having if you play around WPF long enough.

I've tried various solutions, but the one that works best is to use a BindingList like so:

```
public class WorldViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private BindingList<Person> m_People;
   public BindingList<Person> People
   {
      get { return m_People; }
      set
      {
         if(value != m_People)
         {
            m_People = value;
            if(m_People != null)
            {
               m_People.ListChanged += delegate(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs args)
               {
                  OnPeopleListChanged(this);
               };
            }
            RaisePropertyChanged("People");
         }
      }
   }

   private static void OnPeopleListChanged(WorldViewModel vm)
   {
      vm.RaisePropertyChanged("People");
   }

   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
   void RaisePropertyChanged(String prop)
   {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
      {
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
      }
   }
}
```

Then just bind to the People collection like you would do with an ObservableCollection, except bindings will be re-evaluated when any property in its items change.

Also, please note that OnPeopleListChanged is static, so no memory leaks.

And Person should implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Please tell me more about how this works.  What calls OnPeopleListChanged?  Or how does it get called?

Comment: @Blam whenever ListChanged is raised, OnPeopleListChanged is called. ListChanged is much like CollectionChanged in ObservableCollection except it listens for changes within the items of the collection as well.

Comment: It's just your usual method to raise the PropertyChanged event (I'm asusming here that your class implements INotifyPropertyChanged). I've added the code for completeness.

Comment: It only works if the properties of the inner object (Person in the example) is made of primitive types (int, long...). If it contains custom types, they need the same mechanism as m_People.ListChanged except with PropertyChanged. I leave that as an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: Yes, string is a primitive type. I'll take a look.

Comment: Yes I had a mistake.  Not calling the proper PropertyChanged.  I think it works let me test some more before I ask another stupid question.

Comment: +1 final answer.  I am wonder if you could not made this generic?

Answer (score 0):

A CollectionChanged event is only thrown when an item is added or removed from the collection (not when an item in the collection is changed).  So the converter is not called when an item is changed.

One option:
In the Gender Property Set include logic to evaluate the collection and set a string Property that you bind the label to.

Wrote generic version of the answer from Baboon

```
public class ObservalbeList<T>: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private BindingList<T> ts = new BindingList<T>();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property. 
    // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName 
    // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument. 
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged( String propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public BindingList<T> Ts
    {
        get { return ts; }
        set
        {
            if (value != ts)
            {
                Ts = value;
                if (Ts != null)
                {
                    ts.ListChanged += delegate(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs args)
                    {
                        OnListChanged(this);
                    };
                }
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Ts");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void OnListChanged(ObservalbeList<T> vm)
    {
        vm.NotifyPropertyChanged("Ts");
    }

    public ObservalbeList()
    {
        ts.ListChanged += delegate(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            OnListChanged(this);
        };
    }
}
```